# how to dump gitlab ci environment variables to file

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## the question

How to dump all Gitlab CI environment variables (with variables set in the project or group CI/CD settings) to a file, but only them, without environment variables of the host on which gitlab runner is executed?

### Background

We are using gitlab CI/CD to deploy our projects to a docker server. Each project contains a `docker-compose.yml` file which uses various environment variables, eg db passwords. We are using `.env` file to store this variables, so one can start/restart the containers after deployment from command line, without accessing gitlab.

Our deployments script looks something like this:

```
deploy: 
  script:
    #...
    - cp docker-compose.development.yml {$DEPLOY_TO_PATH}/docker-compose.yml
    - env > variables.env
    - docker-compose up -d 
    #...
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  project:
    image: some/image
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    ...
```

The problem is now the `.env` file contains both gitlab variables and hosts system environment variables and in the result **the PATH variable is overwritten**.

I have developed a workaround with `grep`:

```
env | grep -Pv "^PATH" > variables.env
```

It allowed us to keep this working for now, but I think that the problem might hit us again with another variables which would be set to different values inside a container and on the host system.

I know I can list all the variables in docker-compose and similar files, but we already have quite a few of them  in a few projects so it is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to script  next command

```
script:
  ...
  # Read certificate stored in $KUBE_CA_PEM variable and save it in a new file
  - echo "$KUBE_CA_PEM" > variables.env
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the solution we are looking for. Our problem is that we would like to omit some variables while dumping them to file.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I did something like this:

```
  script:
    - env |grep -v "CI"|grep -v "FF"|grep -v "GITLAB"|grep -v "PWD"|grep -v "PATH"|grep -v "HOME"|grep -v "HOST"|grep -v "SH" > application.properties
    - cat application.properties
```

It's not the best, but it works.
The one problem with this is you can have variables with a string containing one of the exclusions, ie. "CI","FF","GITLAB","PWD","PATH","HOME","HOME","SH"

Answer (score 0):

My reusable solution `/tools/gitlab/script-gitlab-variables.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  # Default values
  GITLAB_EXPORT_ENV_FILENAME: '.env.gitlab.cicd'

.script-gitlab-variables:
  debug:
    # section_start
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_start:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_debug[collapsed=true]\r\e[0K[GITLAB VARIABLES DEBUG]"
    # command
    - env
    # section_end
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_end:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_debug\r\e[0K"
  export-to-env:
    # section_start
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_start:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_export_to_env[collapsed=true]\r\e[0K[GITLAB VARIABLES EXPORT]"
    # verify mandatory variables
    - test ! -z "$GITLAB_EXPORT_VARS" && echo "$GITLAB_EXPORT_VARS" || exit $?
    # display variables
    - echo "$GITLAB_EXPORT_ENV_FILENAME"
    # command
    - env | grep -E "^($GITLAB_EXPORT_VARS)=" > $GITLAB_EXPORT_ENV_FILENAME
    # section_end
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_end:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_export_to_env\r\e[0K"
  cat-env:
    # section_start
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_start:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_cat-env[collapsed=true]\r\e[0K[GITLAB VARIABLES CAT ENV]"
    # command
    - cat $GITLAB_EXPORT_ENV_FILENAME
    # section_end
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_end:`date +%s`:gitlab_variables_cat-env\r\e[0K"
```

How to use `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
include:
  - local: '/tools/gitlab/script-gitlab-variables.yml'

Your Job:
  variables:
    GITLAB_EXPORT_VARS: 'CI_BUILD_NAME|GITLAB_USER_NAME'
  script:
    - !reference [.script-gitlab-variables, debug]
    - !reference [.script-gitlab-variables, export-to-env]
    - !reference [.script-gitlab-variables, cat-env]
```

Result `cat .env.gitlab.cicd`:

```
CI_BUILD_NAME=Demo
GITLAB_USER_NAME=Benjamin
```

What you need `dump all`:

```yaml
# /tools/gitlab/script-gitlab-variables.yml
  dump-all:
    - env > $GITLAB_EXPORT_ENV_FILENAME

# .gitlab-ci.yml
  script:
    - !reference [.script-gitlab-variables, dump-all]
```

I hope I could help